# Генератор списков задача квадрат -1

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, генераторы

Подскажите как?

> Используя генератор списков заполните квадратный массив целыми числами
> по образцу.
>
> Пример для `n=5`
>
> ```
> 0 1 2 3 4
> 1 1 2 3 4
> 2 2 2 3 4
> 3 3 3 3 4
> 4 4 4 4 4
> ```

Comment: Генерируйте от 0 до 4. Обратите внимание на повторы в начале строки и соотнесите их с номером строки.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
N = 5
items = [
    [max(i, j) for j in range(N)] for i in range(N)
]
print(items)

print('\n'.join(map(str, items)))
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
# [1, 1, 2, 3, 4]
# [2, 2, 2, 3, 4]
# [3, 3, 3, 3, 4]
# [4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

Answer (score 3):

Возможно я сделал это немного коряво, но вот решение.
Мы заполняем каждый элемент массива значениями, согласно его индексу в массиве.
Если значение элемента меньше индекса самого элемента, мы пишем индекс, иначе значение.

```
def list_gen(n):
    newList = [i for i in range(n)]
    for k in newList:
        indx = newList.index(k)
        yield [(lambda x: i if i > indx else indx)(i) for i in newList]


print([i for i in list_gen(5)])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [4]: N = 5

In [5]: [[x] * x + list(range(x,N)) for x in range(N)]
Out[5]:
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
 [1, 1, 2, 3, 4],
 [2, 2, 2, 3, 4],
 [3, 3, 3, 3, 4],
 [4, 4, 4, 4, 4]]
```

Асимптоматическая сложность приближена к `O(N)`.